# Book Recommendations About Using Mathematica in Topics like Calculus of Variation and Optimization?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, reference-request, variational-calculus

I want to use effectively Mathematica about topics like Calculus of variation and Optimization. Do you know books about it?
or what do you suggest me?

Comment: Google is a good start.